# Bootstrap tour infinite loop

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am trying to get the tour to redirect to another page, but when it redirects it enters a loop. tried all i can. Right now i am using path, i have tried using onNext and the tour just doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
    <script>
        // Instance the tour
    var tour = new Tour({
      steps: [
      <?php
      if(!$master_id)
      {
      ?>
          {

      placement:"bottom",
  backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#user_signin",
title: "Sign in to your account",
content: "Click here to see the sign in form"
      }, 
 {
      placement:"bottom",
  backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#user_signup",
title: "Create a new account",
content: "Click here to see the sign up form"
      }, 
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      {

      placement:"bottom",
  backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#user_location",
title: "Choose your location",
content: "Select your location so we can show you tailored results and service providers close to you."
      },
      {
      placement:"top",
  backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#autocomplete",
title: "Search for a service",
content: "Search for any service you require, our service categories range from automobile repairs to fashion design."
      },
      {
  placement:"top",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#autocompleteCity",
title: "Select a location",
content: "You can also select a particular location and search for a service in that location"
      },
       {
  placement:"top",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#all_categories",
title: "Select a service category",
content: "Visit a service category and view businesses in that category and those around you"
      },
      {

  placement:"top",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#footer",
title: "Useful links",
content: "Other useful links you may need."
      },
      {
  placement:"top",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:5000,
element: "#google_translate_element",
title: "Choose your language",
content: "Not fluent in english? select your prefered language."
      },
      {
  path: "s.php",
    placement:"bottom",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:4000,
element: "#all_search_result",
title: "View all results",
content: "View all results from your search"
      },
      {
  path: "s.php",
  placement:"bottom",
       backdrop:true,
  duration:4000,
element: "#my_search_result",
title: "View tailored results",
content: "View search results based on your selected location"
      }


      ],
      keyboard: true,
      redirect: true,




      }).init().start(true);


        </script>
```

Comment: no i didn't, ended up not using it

Comment: same for me, ended up using tourbus, ... its stripped down and makes alot more sense

Comment: You might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106349/bootstrap-tour-initiating-multipage