# Bootstrap Tour is looping on first step [wordpress]

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I have implimented the tour into my wordpress site, but it loops at the first step, I only have a small amount of code here. So I am not sure where the problem could be. Does anyone have any experience with this?

```
var tour = new Tour({
  debug: true,
  storage: false,
  steps: [
  {
    orphan: true,
    title: "DTC ZERO TOUR",
    content: "This tour will show you where important information is, so you never miss a thing!"
  },
  {
    orphan: true,
    title: "Second Title",
    content: "Some directional type stuff"
  }
]});

tour.init(true);
tour.start();
```

let me know if there is something more I should show you.  Both the css and js are being read. Just stuck in a continuous loop

Comment: Have you already read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106349/bootstrap-tour-initiating-multipage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue caused by using multiple 'orphan' steps - this got broken between Bootstrap V3.0.0 and V3.3.4 but I'm not sure exactly when... anyway, if you roll your Bootstrap version back to V3.0.0 you won't have this problem anymore.